# how to animate:flip with in/out:fade?

Tags: css-animations, svelte, svelte-transition

I am trying to animate a changing list of elements, where some disappear, some move, and some appear.

Ideal animation sequence:

1. Old elements fade out
2. Existing elements move from old position to new position
3. New elements fade in

The problem (bug?) is that the old elements, as they fade out, appear stacked on top of each other at the top or bottom of the list.

Can I not use `animate:flip` and `transition:fade` (`in`/`out` shorthand) at the same time?

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/5feb66e2ac544e10a11b98890c1b24dd?version=3.55.1

Code here for completeness:

```
<script>
    import { flip } from 'svelte/animate'
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition'
    
    let startInt = 0
    $:items = Array(5).fill().map((x,i) => i+startInt)
    function shiftDown() {
        startInt = startInt + 3
    }
    function shiftUp() {
        startInt = startInt - 3
    }
</script>

<a href="#" on:click|preventDefault="{e => shiftUp()}">up</a>

{#each items as item (item)}
    <div
             animate:flip="{{delay: 1000, duration: 1000}}"
             in:fade="{{delay: 2000, duration: 1000}}"
             out:fade="{{duration: 1000}}"
    >
        {item}
    </div>
{/each}

<a href="#" on:click|preventDefault="{e => shiftDown()}">down</a>
```

[image: List of items with buddy fade out]

Comment: I think you're looking for the [slide](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-transition-slide) transition effect? Simply use `<div transition:slide>` looks decent enough to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the elements in a container with `display: flex` seems to solve the problem

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ffedff6a588043a0bb312fb4ef026e25?version=3.53.1)

```
<script>
    import { flip } from 'svelte/animate'
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition'

    let startInt = 0
    $:items = Array(5).fill().map((x,i) => i+startInt)
    
    function shiftDown() {
        startInt = startInt + 3
    }
    function shiftUp() {
        startInt = startInt - 3
    }
</script>

<button on:click={shiftUp}>up</button>

<div id="wrapper">
    {#each items as item (item)}
    <div
             animate:flip="{{delay: 1000, duration: 1000}}"
             in:fade="{{delay: 2000, duration: 1000}}"
             out:fade="{{duration: 1000}}"
             >
        {item}
    </div>
    {/each}
</div>

<button on:click={shiftDown}>down</button>

<style>
    #wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Interesting finding. Do you have an explanation for it?

Comment: @hackape Looking at the CSS of the vanishing elements they have a `transform: translate()` property during the animation inside the flex container and it's missing in the other case. But I don't know why that is. Would guess it's a bug because Svelte should set the property as well in the other case..?