# Why does adding an if block prevent Svelte transitions from playing?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-transition

I'm working on some code where I `fetch` some items in `onMount` then render them. I don't want to play a ton of transitions for the big batch of `fetch`ed items. However, I do want to play transitions when individual items are added or removed from the list. This is a similar situation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191633/prevent-svelte-transition-on-first-render-after-onmount).

If I write this, then I get the transition behavior I want.

```
{#if itemsFetched}
    {#each items as it (it.id)}
        <div transition:slide|local>
            <span>{it.id} {it.name}</span>
            <button on:click={removeItem(it)}>remove</button>
        </div>
    {/each}
{/if}
```

However, inside of the `each` block, I need to render the items 1 of 2 ways. For this example, I render even IDs one way and odd IDs another. If I add an `if` block, then the individual item transitions don't play at all.

```
{#if itemsFetched}
    {#each items as it (it.id)}
        {#if it.id%2 === 0}
            <div transition:slide|local>
                <span>render like this {it.id} {it.name}</span>
                <button on:click={removeItem(it)}>remove</button>
            </div>
        {:else}
            <div transition:slide|local>
                <span>render this other way {it.id} {it.name}</span>
                <button on:click={removeItem(it)}>remove</button>
            </div>
        {/if}
    {/each}
{/if}
```

Here's a full example.
Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-heyrovsky-bwviny?file=/App.svelte

```
<script>
import { slide } from "svelte/transition";
import { onMount } from "svelte";

// Initially we have no items.
let items = [];
let id = 0;

let itemsFetched = false;
onMount(() => {
    // Fetch items from API.
    items = [
        {id: id, name: `item ${id++}`},
        {id: id, name: `item ${id++}`},
        {id: id, name: `item ${id++}`},
    ];
    itemsFetched = true;
});

function addItem() {
    items = [
        ...items,
        {id: id, name: `item ${id++}`},
    ];
}

function removeItem(rmIt) {
    return () => {
        items = items.filter(it => it.id !== rmIt.id);
    };
}
</script>

<div>
    <button on:click={addItem}>add</button>

    {#if itemsFetched}
        {#each items as it (it.id)}
            {#if it.id%2 === 0}
                <div transition:slide|local>
                    <span>render like this {it.id} {it.name}</span>
                    <button on:click={removeItem(it)}>remove</button>
                </div>
            {:else}
                <div transition:slide|local>
                    <span>render this other way {it.id} {it.name}</span>
                    <button on:click={removeItem(it)}>remove</button>
                </div>
            {/if}
        {/each}
    {/if}
</div>
```

Why does adding an `if` block break the `local` transition? If I remove `local`, then the items play transitions when added or removed, but then I lose the initial `onMount` behavior I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local` restricts the transition to the creation/destruction of the block the element is in, which is the `{#if it.id%2 === 0}`. But since the ID presumably never changes, the block just always exists, i.e. there is no change and hence no animation is triggered.

Put the `{#if}` inside the element with the transition.

Instead of this:

```
{#each items as it (it.id)}
    {#if it.id%2 === 0}
        <div transition:slide|local>
            <span>render like this {it.id} {it.name}</span>
            <button on:click={removeItem(it)}>remove</button>
        </div>
    {:else}
        <div transition:slide|local>
            <span>render this other way {it.id} {it.name}</span>
            <button on:click={removeItem(it)}>remove</button>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/each}
```

Do this:

```
{#each items as it (it.id)}
    <div transition:slide|local>
        {#if it.id%2 === 0}
            <span>render like this {it.id} {it.name}</span>
            <button on:click={removeItem(it)}>remove</button>
        {:else}
            <span>render this other way {it.id} {it.name}</span>
            <button on:click={removeItem(it)}>remove</button>
        {/if}
    </div>
{/each}
```

Comment: "the block just always exists"—but I have buttons to delete existing divs and add new ones, so the IDs are constantly changing. Also, I just updated the `if` condition to be closer to what I'm actually doing. Sorry for the confusion, I'm not trying to filter items. I need to render them differently.

Comment: The ID does not change for the individual items, you just add and remove items. Just put the `if` *inside* the `div` with the transition.

Comment: Oooh, that worked. So the elements inside of `<div transition:slide|local>` need to be created or destroyed for the transition to work? If the `<div transition:slide|local>` itself is created or destroyed, that doesn't count? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: No, the changes to the block outside the element governs the transition, so it's the `{#each}`, i.e. adding/removing items.

Comment: Sorry, what does "the block" and "the element" refer to?

Comment: Directives like `{#if}` and `f#each}` form a block. The element is the `div` with the transition on it, a DOM element.